# InDesign: Is there any way to lock all the styles (paragraph and character) and master pages and keep all of them in a master document only?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm setting up a workflow for working in a book with various chapters and I don't want the designers to change the styles in one document in the book. I just want to be able to change the styles in a master document.

I know about the sync feature but is very poor, because I cannot delete a style. Also allows other documents to be the master, which is very bad in our case.

What would be really nice would be a book to be linked to a styles library. SO you don't need any sync.

Maybe a script could do that, I don't know.. Other alternatives?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to solve a communication problem with software/scripts. What exactly keeps you from asking the designers not to change the paragraph styles?

Comment: I'm asking but they are not so experienced and change it. I've removed the direct change panel, which changes the font and other things without applying to a style.

Comment: I still think that smarting up the designers is better than dumbing down the software. You want them to be responsible workers and I don't think that can be done by taking responsibility away. Have you asked them why they change it? Maybe there is a good reason.

Comment: I thought I've replied but here it is: this is very rare, but I would like to be locked so I'm sure there is nothing broken in my files. This is not so bad because the book sync will remove their style changes (but they can create new styles, but this is more intentional so will 'never' happen)

Comment: You have explained your reasons. It's not that I don't understand them. The situation is just that software designed to give designers freedom can't just be locked down. It would defeat its purpose. And the effort would certainly be greater than talking to your designers for 15min.

Comment: I don't think it defeat it's purpose because not everything is to be changed. Why in the world would you want to have the text on some pages starting at 1mm, on others at 10mm and so on from the left and top of the page. Not all freedom is good! I've talked way more than 15 min and it's still happens. The other day I had to change the position of the textframe and then manually check 400 pages for offset textframes: there were about 30 offset-ed pages. It should have a lock for size/width, just like it has "Allow master item overrides".

Comment: I don't want that. That's a straw man argument. But sophisticated layout software has its focus on editing, not on locking it. I am not you so I can't talk to your designers. But moving text boxes off grid is bad designing. So I still believe it's a designer error and not a software error. Either way, I don't know of a way to lock down InDesign. I can only tell you what I expect from designers I work with and how I would solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using InCopy and not letting these content-creators mess with your design decisions?

Comment: There are a lot of tables that needs to be resized to the right size. Each column width is defined by the designers based on the data that has to be inserted into the table

Answer (score 0):

The palettes in InDesign are implemented as plug-ins. You can remove the ones you don't want people to have access to.

Write a script which hooks into document open/close and forces synchronization against a file only you have permission to edit.